# Hover em DIV1 alterar DIV2 com CSS

Tags: css, seletores

Se eu tiver um `#div1` e um `#div2`, e **eles forem irmãos**, sei que posso usar o seletor `~` para estilizar a `#div2` da seguinte forma:

```
#div1:hover ~ #div2 { /* regras */ }
```

Existe algum seletor equivalente para estilizar a `#div2` quando um evento `#div1:hover` ocorrer na estrutura a seguir?

```html
<div id="pai"> 
    <div id="div1"></div> 
</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: Via CSS não, as regras aplicam-se ao _próprio_, _filhos do próprio_ ou _irmãos do próprio_. O que pretendes é se o _filho_ estiver com `:hover`, o _tio_ fica "vermelho". Para isso só mesmo JavaScript.

Comment: Preconceito com os tios :/
Vlw @Zuul

Comment: Atualmente só é possível se div2 estiver no mesmo nível de div1, no seu caso div2 não está no mesmo nível, e assim não será possível aplicar um CSS na div2 a partir de div1. [Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6910112/6510304)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estão usando os marcadores errados, veja esse exemplo:

```
#pai:first-child:hover ~ #div2 {
    background: #999
}
```

---

```
<div id="pai"> 
    <div id='div1'>CONTEUDO 1</div>
</div>

<div id='div'>NADA</div>
<div id='div'>NADA</div>
<div id='div'>NADA</div>

<div id='div2'>CONTEUDO 2</div>
```

Se eles não forem **parentes** você não consegue achar, mas pode indicar um elemento que seja **parente** e navegar pelos filhos pra indicar o hover.

Comment: O único problema nessa solução, é que você não consegue ser muito especifico no elemento filho.

Comment: Um id `#` parece específico o suficiente hehe. Conheço essa lógica, eu havia tentado com `:has(#div:hover)`, mas não obtive sucesso pois os browsers ainda não suportam ele, o que me levou a criar a questão. Muito boa a solução, valeu!

Comment: Acredito também que deve haver um jeito de indicar com precisão usando :nth-child(key) puxando de #pai, e ainda ser possível com essa relação indicar estilos a elementos dentro de outra div como #tio:nth-child(key) em condição do primeiro hover, vou testar depois se der certo acrescento na resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Com javascript é possível.

Segue um exemplo usando jquery:

```js
$("#div1").hover(function() {
  $("#div2").toggleClass("vermelho");
}, function() {
  $("#div2").toggleClass("vermelho");
});
```

```css
#div1, #div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

.azul {
  background-color: #00F;
}

.vermelho {
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pai"> 
    <div id="div1" class="azul"></div> 
</div>
<div id="div2" class="vermelho"></div>
```

Comment: é possivel, nem lembro mais em que aplicação estava usando isso, mas eu acabei resolvendo. Vote up pela resposta bem bolada, mas ainda n é a solução kkkkk. O post vai ficar por aqui, daqui a pouco vamos descobrir um jeito só pelo CSS. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Atualmente não é possível selecionar o pai de um elemento via CSS.

Todos seletores disponíveis atualmente estão nas especificações:

- [Seletores CSS3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)
- [Seletores CSS2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching)

Por enquanto, este comportamento só é possível com JavaScript

---

Os [Selectors Level 4 Working Draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#relational) incluem a `:has()` pseudo-classe que funciona da mesma forma que a [implementação jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/). Até Agosto de 2017, **[isto não é suportado por nenhum navegador](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has)**.

Comment: Na verdade [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/229846/20070) foi possível com um seletor nível 3.

Answer (score 0):

Por enquanto ainda não é possível via css, mas você pode fazer este comportamento via Javascript conforme exemplos anteriores. É possível alterar o comportamento de um elemento dentro do mesmo container, ou selecionar sub elementos.

```css
#pai div,
#div3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

.azul {
  background-color: #00F;
}

.vermelho {
  background-color: #F00;
}


#div1:hover + #div2,
#pai:first-child:hover + #div3,
#pai:last-child:hover + #div3
{
  background-color: #0F0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="pai"> 
    <div id="div1" class="azul"></div> 
    <div id="div2" class="vermelho"></div>
</div>
<div id="div3" class="vermelho"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente:

```
#div1:hover + #div2 {
    background-color:red;
}
```

ou

```
#div1:hover ~ #div2 {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Dá uma olhada em:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered

Comment: Isto não condiz com o HTML do autor da pergunta, simplesmente não vai funcionar.

Comment: Infelizmente não funciona. Segue [teste nesse link](https://jsfiddle.net/aLz1s8sf/)

Answer (score -4):

Existe sim.
Exemplo

```
<div id="pai"> 
    <div id="div1"></div> 
</div>
<div id="div2"></div>

<style>
    #div1:hover #div2{
        background-color:red;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling

Comment: Isso não funciona assim, este seletor que vc exemplificou seleciona todos elementos com ID #div2 que sejam filhas do Hover do ID #div1

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu a pergunta.